# Is there any Scottish population still present in Kalimpong, West Bengal, India?

Tags: religion, india, population

During the late 1800s, the Scottish missionaries set up a large number of schools and churches in Kalimpong (present day in West Bengal, India).

Is there any Scottish population that is still there, who maintains their separate identity?

Comment: Is this a question about history or about the current day?  What research has been done, and what did you learn?

Comment: I searched the google for a long time but was unable to get any details past the colonial era. I want to know whether all the Scottish families went home or some choose to stay behind while still maintaining their separate identity.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a McDonald's there. (Sorry, I couldn't resist.)

Comment: bdw nice place to visit, in my list, thanks @Sonevol

Comment: I'd be surprised if there are. It's possible that some individuals of mixed heritage may have stayed, although many were [sent to New Zealand](http://www.kalimpongkids.org.nz/)